# How to wrap same class elements in list box using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom

Please check my code below I want to display same class element like red in the wrap in one div. I have described in comment area in the code snippet. Please check comment section and gives me a suggestion how we can do. In code i have use a jQuery function nextUntil() with wrapAll() method. to wrap all same element in one div but its wrap div also as a child node.

```js
jQuery('.row').find('li').each(function() {
 if(jQuery(this).hasClass('red')) {
  jQuery(this).prev().nextUntil( "li.blank" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
  jQuery(this).prev().nextUntil( "li.blank" ).wrapAll('<div class="new"></div>');
 }
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
 
 
 <div class="row">
   <div class="centering">
    <ul>
     <li class="blank">list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one list one list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one list one list one list one</li>
     <li class="red">list one list one list one list one list one</li>
     <li class="red">list one</li>
     <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
     <li class="red blue">list one list one list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one list one list one</li>
     <li class="red">list one list one list one list one list one</li>
     <li class="red blue">list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one</li>
     <li class="red">list one</li>
     <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
     <li class="red">list one list one list one</li>
     <li class="red">list one</li>
     <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
     <li class="red">list one list one list one</li>
     <li class="red">list one</li>
     <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
     <li class="red">list one list one list one</li>
     <li class="red">list one</li>
     <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
     <li class="red blue">list one list one list one</li>
     
    </ul>
    </div> 
   </div>
      
     <!-- 
      I want to result like as below
   <div class="row">
    <ul>
     <li class="blank">list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one list one list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one list one list one list one</li>
          <div class="new">
        <li class="red">list one list one list one list one list one</li>
       <li class="red">list one</li>
       <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
       <li class="red blue">list one list one list one</li>
          </div>
     <li class="blank">list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one list one list one</li>
          <div class="new">
       <li class="red">list one list one list one list one list one</li>
       <li class="red blue">list one</li>
          </div>
     <li class="blank">list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one</li>
          <div class="new">
       <li class="red">list one</li>
       <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
       <li class="red">list one list one list one</li>
       <li class="red">list one</li>
       <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
       <li class="red">list one list one list one</li>
       <li class="red">list one</li>
       <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
       <li class="red">list one list one list one</li>
       <li class="red">list one</li>
       <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
       <li class="red blue">list one list one list one</li>
          </div>
     
    </ul>
  </div>
 
 --> 
 
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: UL cant have a div child only LI is allowed this is invalid HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if **previous element** has `red` class or not.

```
jQuery('.row').find('li.red').each(function() {
    if ( !jQuery(this).prev().hasClass( "red" ))
    {
      var matches = jQuery(this).prev().nextUntil("li.blank");
      matches.wrapAll('<div class="new"></div>');
      matches.css("background-color", "red");
    }
    //jQuery(this).prev().nextUntil("li.blank").add().css("background-color", "red");
   // jQuery(this).nextUntil("li.blank").wrapAll('<div class="new"></div>');
});
```

**Demo**

```js
jQuery('.row').find('li.red').each(function() {
    if ( !jQuery(this).prev().hasClass( "red" ))
    {
      var matches = jQuery(this).prev().nextUntil("li.blank");
      matches.wrapAll('<div class="new"></div>');
      matches.css("background-color", "red");
    }
    //jQuery(this).prev().nextUntil("li.blank").add().css("background-color", "red");
   // jQuery(this).nextUntil("li.blank").wrapAll('<div class="new"></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="centering">
    <ul>
      <li class="blank">list one</li>
      <li class="blank">list one list one</li>
      <li class="blank">list one list one list one</li>
      <li class="blank">list one list one list one list one</li>
      <li class="red">list one list one list one list one list one</li>
      <li class="red">list one</li>
      <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
      <li class="red blue">list one list one list one</li>
      <li class="blank">list one</li>
      <li class="blank">list one list one</li>
      <li class="blank">list one list one list one</li>
      <li class="red">list one list one list one list one list one</li>
      <li class="red blue">list one</li>
      <li class="blank">list one</li>
      <li class="blank">list one</li>
      <li class="red">list one</li>
      <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
      <li class="red">list one list one list one</li>
      <li class="red">list one</li>
      <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
      <li class="red">list one list one list one</li>
      <li class="red">list one</li>
      <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
      <li class="red">list one list one list one</li>
      <li class="red">list one</li>
      <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
      <li class="red blue">list one list one list one</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 concept to get your result first on page laod and secound on button click  below concept i have implement jquery function and do the coloring as you need

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
 // on button click
  $('#listHeighlight').click(function(){
  $('.new').find('li.red').css('background','red')
  $('.new').find('li.blue').css('background','blue')
  //you can add your custom class
  //$('.new').find('li').addClass('red')
  })
  
 // onpageload page load you can uncomment below code
 // $('.new').find('li.red').css('background','red')
  //$('.new').find('li.blue').css('background','blue')
  //you can add your custom class
  //$('.new').find('li').addClass('red')
  })
  </script>
  
  </head>
 <body>
 
 
 <input type="button" id="listHeighlight" value="List Highlight" / >
      
  
   <div class="row">
    <ul>
     <li class="blank">list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one list one list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one list one list one list one</li>
          <div class="new">
        <li class="red">list one list one list one list one list one</li>
       <li class="red">list one</li>
       <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
       <li class="red blue">list one list one list one</li>
          </div>
     <li class="blank">list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one list one list one</li>
          <div class="new">
       <li class="red">list one list one list one list one list one</li>
       <li class="red blue">list one</li>
          </div>
     <li class="blank">list one</li>
     <li class="blank">list one</li>
          <div class="new">
       <li class="red">list one</li>
       <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
       <li class="red">list one list one list one</li>
       <li class="red">list one</li>
       <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
       <li class="red">list one list one list one</li>
       <li class="red">list one</li>
       <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
       <li class="red">list one list one list one</li>
       <li class="red">list one</li>
       <li class="red"> list one list one</li>
       <li class="red blue">list one list one listone</li>
          </div>
     
    </ul>
  </div>
 
 
 </body>

</html>
```